# How to Fill Data From Database to datagridview and combobox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I need to Fill data from database to my Datagrid and two Combobox.

I have 3 tables, "Tipo", "Marca" and "Modelo".
The table "Modelo" have two foreign key from "Tipo" and "Marca".

[image: Print]

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CarregarDados()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CarregarDados()
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=automoveldb"
        cn.Open()
        'Load DataGridView
        Try
            With Cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT modelo.id Id, marca.Nome NomeMarca, tipo.Nome NomeTipo, modelo.Nome NomeModelo FROM modelo INNER JOIN Marca ON marca.id = modelo.IdMarca JOIN tipo ON tipo.id = modelo.IdTipo;"
                .Connection = cn
            End With
            MsgBox(Cmd.CommandText)
            With Da
                .SelectCommand = Cmd
                .Fill(dt)
                dgvModelo.DataSource = dt
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try

        '*************************
        Try
            With Cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tipo;"
                .Connection = cn
            End With
            MsgBox(Cmd.CommandText)
            With Da
                .SelectCommand = Cmd
                .Fill(dt)
                cmbTipo.ValueMember = "Id"
                cmbTipo.DisplayMember = "Nome"
                cmbTipo.DataSource = dt
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

MyDatabase

[image]

Result my code

[image]

My combobox Type was filled but added in the datagridview a new column, i dont want it

Comment: Could you explain what is your problem?

Comment: are you getting an error?  all the DB objects being used there just pop out of no where without being instanced.  what DB are you using

Comment: I can't load data to my combobox, just datagridview, i'll edit wait

Comment: see 'load combo, is this way that i try to do, but, not work!

Comment: If i do my SQL like this -> "SELECT * FROM MODELO", In DatagridView, my columns will show "id", "idTipo", "idMarca", "Nome", but i want to show the name, why did Join

Comment: build the query in access so you can fine tune the results, then copy the SQL to your code

Comment: My query is "SELECT modelo.id Id, marca.Nome NomeMarca, tipo.Nome NomeTipo, modelo.Nome NomeModelo FROM modelo INNER JOIN Marca ON marca.id = modelo.IdMarca JOIN tipo ON tipo.id = modelo.IdTipo;" But now i dont know, Do I reuze  it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for that problem, so if somebody want fill a datagrid and combobox in a same Function, do it:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CarregarDados()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CarregarDados()
        cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=automoveldb"
        cn.Open()
        '***********************Load DataGridView
        Try
            With Cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT modelo.id Id, marca.Nome NomeMarca, tipo.Nome NomeTipo, modelo.Nome NomeModelo FROM modelo INNER JOIN Marca ON marca.id = modelo.IdMarca JOIN tipo ON tipo.id = modelo.IdTipo;"
                .Connection = cn
            End With
            With Da
                .SelectCommand = Cmd
                .Fill(dt)
                dgvModelo.DataSource = dt
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
        '************************* Load ComboBox Tipo
        Try
            With Cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tipo;"
                .Connection = cn
            End With

            With Da
                .SelectCommand = Cmd
                .Fill(ds, "tipo")
            End With

            cmbTipo.ValueMember = "Id"
            cmbTipo.DisplayMember = "Nome"
            cmbTipo.DataSource = ds.Tables("tipo")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try

        '************************* Load ComboBox Marca
        Try
            With Cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Marca;"
                .Connection = cn
            End With

            With Da
                .SelectCommand = Cmd
                .Fill(ds, "marca")
            End With

            cmbMarca.ValueMember = "Id"
            cmbMarca.DisplayMember = "Nome"
            cmbMarca.DataSource = ds.Tables("marca")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```